# Amplify GraphQL - Allow owner access to certain rows and everyone access to certain rows

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a use case in Amplify GraphQL where I need certain rows to be access by only the owners (people who created them) and other rows to be readable by everyone. How can I achieve that using Amplify @auth parameters. There is a attribute value in the model that determines which are owner accessed and which are general read. How do I use the @auth to achieve this? I can easily use two tables to do this but there are some common processes that act on all rows in the same way.

Has anyone implemented this and can they share an example?